# Android build error : duplicate entry: okio/AsyncTimeout$1.class

Tags: android

I added a intel webrtc library into my ./libs folder. And added this line in build.gradle

```
compile files('./libs/woogeenconference.jar')
```

After that, i start getting

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForUserStaging'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: okio/AsyncTimeout$1.class
```

How do I deal with this build error? I am using some other android packages as well. I think this is containing the same class.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
compile files('./libs/woogeenconference.jar') {
    exclude group: 'okhttp', module: 'okhttp'
}
```

Comment: I get this error instead Error:(166, 0) Could not find method exclude() for arguments [{group=okhttp, module=okhttp}] on file collection of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.
<a href="openFile:/Users/somepath/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: too bad. Sorry then - I know one can exclude in a ``compile(....)`` call to gradle - I was not sure whether it would work with ``compile files`` too. Sorry.